# error in SQL syntax create table

Tags: mysql, sql

I was trying to feed the following commands to MySQL CLI with
, which seems to be good, however when I added one more table, it complained there was an error in syntax.

Here are the commands

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS User(
        uid INT,
        name VARCHAR(64) UNIQUE,
        birthday date,
        PRIMARY KEY(uid)
) ENGINE = InnoDB ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS UserEmail(
        uid INT,
        email VARCHAR(64),
        PRIMARY KEY(uid, email),
        FOREIGN KEY(uid) REFERENCES User(uid)
);
```

However if I wanted to add one more table, it said there's an syntax error near the ')' at the line where PRIMARY KEY(uid) lies.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS User(
        uid INT,
        name VARCHAR(64) UNIQUE,
        birthday date,
        PRIMARY KEY(uid)
) ENGINE = InnoDB ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS UserEmail(
        uid INT,
        email VARCHAR(64),
        PRIMARY KEY(uid, email),
        FOREIGN KEY(uid) REFERENCES User(uid)
);

CREATE TABLE friendship(
        invite_uid  INT,
        accept_uid  INT,
        start_date  DATE,
        PRIMARY KEY(invite_uid, accept_uid),
        FOREIGN KEY(invite_uid) REFERENCES User(uid),
        FOREIGN KEY(accept_uid) REFERENCES User(uid),
);
```

Not sure where went wrong since the error was not complained in the newly added command.

**--UPDATE--**

Well that was fixed, but there's one more problem. 
Adding the following table throws

**cannot create table "estore.contains" (errorno: 150)**

```
CREATE TABLE contains(
        uid INT,
        wid INT,
        pid INT,
        PRIMARY KEY(uid, wid, pid),
        FOREIGN KEY(uid) REFERENCES User(uid),
        FOREIGN KEY(wid) REFERENCES Wishlist(wid),          
        FOREIGN KEY(pid) REFERENCES Product(pid)        
);
```

**--UPDATE 2--**

Full Tables that I want to add

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS User(
        uid INT,
        name VARCHAR(64) UNIQUE,
        birthday date,
        PRIMARY KEY(uid)
) ENGINE = InnoDB ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS UserEmail(
        uid INT,
        email VARCHAR(64),
        PRIMARY KEY(uid, email),
        FOREIGN KEY(uid) REFERENCES User(uid)
);

CREATE TABLE friendship(
        invite_uid  INT,
        accept_uid  INT,
        start_date  DATE,
        PRIMARY KEY(invite_uid, accept_uid),
        FOREIGN KEY(invite_uid) REFERENCES User(uid),
        FOREIGN KEY(accept_uid) REFERENCES User(uid)
);  

CREATE TABLE Seller(
        sid INT,
        name VARCHAR(64),
        PRIMARY KEY(sid)
);

CREATE TABLE Product(
        pid INT,
        sid INT,
        name VARCHAR(64),
        description TEXT,
        price DOUBLE,
        PRIMARY KEY(pid),
        FOREIGN KEY(sid) REFERENCES Seller(sid)
);

CREATE TABLE buy(
        uid INT,
        pid INT,
        time DATE,
        PRIMARY KEY(uid, pid),
        FOREIGN KEY(uid) REFERENCES User(uid),
        FOREIGN KEY(pid) REFERENCES Product(pid)
);

CREATE TABLE Wishlist(
        uid INT,
        wid INT,
        start_time DATE,
        end_time DATE,
        PRIMARY KEY(uid,wid),
        FOREIGN KEY(uid) REFERENCES User(uid)
);

CREATE TABLE conntains(
        uid INT,
        wid INT,
        pid INT,
        PRIMARY KEY(uid, wid, pid),
        FOREIGN KEY(uid) REFERENCES User(uid),
        FOREIGN KEY(wid) REFERENCES Wishlist(wid),          
        FOREIGN KEY(pid) REFERENCES Product(pid)        
)ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Anyone could help? Thx

Comment: Please add Table Structure for Wishlist and Product. Also use ENGINE = InnoDB for all of your tables As foreign key will not be created when table is non-innodb (Some server have default myisam engine instead of innodb Also It may not throw error for using myisam or not using engine statement )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FOREIGN KEY(accept_uid) REFERENCES User(uid),<-- Comma should be removed
```

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE friendship(
        invite_uid  INT,
        accept_uid  INT,
        start_date  DATE,
        PRIMARY KEY(invite_uid, accept_uid),
        FOREIGN KEY(invite_uid) REFERENCES User(uid),
        FOREIGN KEY(accept_uid) REFERENCES User(uid)
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the last line of your code

```
FOREIGN KEY(accept_uid) REFERENCES User(uid),
```

Remove the comma at the end.

Answer (score 2):

remove `,` a end of line

```
FOREIGN KEY(accept_uid) REFERENCES User(uid),
--------------------------------------------^
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an extra comma on the third table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS User(
        uid INT,
        name VARCHAR(64) UNIQUE,
        birthday date,
        PRIMARY KEY(uid)
) ENGINE = InnoDB ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS UserEmail(
        uid INT,
        email VARCHAR(64),
        PRIMARY KEY(uid, email),
        FOREIGN KEY(uid) REFERENCES User(uid)
);

CREATE TABLE friendship(
        invite_uid  INT,
        accept_uid  INT,
        start_date  DATE,
        PRIMARY KEY(invite_uid, accept_uid),
        FOREIGN KEY(invite_uid) REFERENCES User(uid),
        FOREIGN KEY(accept_uid) REFERENCES User(uid), <---- Extra comma
);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel, you cannot use the name **CONTAINS** for a table since its an SQL keyword. Please create the table with some other name.

Comment: No I guess it isn't the cause, changing it to another name doesn't solve the problem. I think it's related to FK, but not sure exactly how

Comment: Daniel, you can use only 1 Primary key for a table. That should be causing the issue for you.

Comment: but what if I have to use a combined primary key. I have updated my question to make the context clearer.As you can see, the referenced Product(wid) is part of its primary key combination (wid,uid)

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately I figured the second problem out, the foreign key was not made right, I need to use

```
        FOREIGN KEY(uid, wid) REFERENCES Wishlist(uid, wid),
```

to refer the the primary key combination in Wishlist